# Write number inside the end of ayah sysmbol

Tags: html, css

I'm working on HTML application and I'm trying to write the arabic number inside Arabic end of ayah symbol (۝) into textview. I've tried to write the end of ayah symbol then the Arabic number without any space but it didn't work. I'm using a uthmani font.

I want to display it like this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fFOG.png

This is Unicode:
`&#1757;`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way. Try adding the ayah symbol as the content of a pseudo element like `::after` and position it centered around its parent.  I converted the html entity code to css hex code using http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html.

I didn't try it with the uthmani font so you'll likely need to adjust the `font-size` and `padding` but the concept should get you on your way to success.

```css
.ayah {
  padding: 0 .5em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.ayah::after {
  content: "\06DD";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<span class="ayah">5</span>

<p>Here's one in a paragraph. <span class="ayah">5</span></p>
```